# How to erase a published Git commit from history?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally committed a change with Git, pushed it up to GitHub, and have done several commits afterward.  I need to erase that commit from the history.  I realize this could possibly hose other forks and I'm ok with that.

I was able to modify my history locally with a command like:

```
git rebase --onto HEAD~4 HEAD~3 HEAD
```

which seemed to work fine.  However, I don't then know how to get that changed history pushed appropriately back to github.

Comment: `git push --force` - Git won't let you erase history without specifying the --force/-f flag.

Comment: actually the problem was that I was no longer on HEAD, git status said there were no changes, and git push said there was nothing to push.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have any merges you need to conserve them with

```
git rebase -i --preserve-merges commit^
```

Otherwise, git will flatten your history.

Then push with the force option.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to accomplish the whole process a different way after some messing around:

```
git rebase -i <commit>^
... delete first commit in editor ...
git push -f
```